# How to configure SSRS Configuration with Azure Managed Instance?

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services

Is there anyone who have configured SSRS with Azure MI, as we are trying to do this at our end, but the web portal is giving us error of 503?

Comment: Is this [documentation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/hosting-ssrs-databases-in-azure-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/1700197) helpful for you?

Comment: @JosephXu we have looked at this documentation but it does not help us since we are encountering the error on our side not sure what we have missed.

Comment: What about this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/17d3d563-d79b-4e54-bba9-5a64c247ce8d/how-to-fix-problem-503-service-unavailable-in-ssrs-?forum=sqlreportingservices)?

Comment: @JosephXu thanks for the answer but we have looked at both the answers as well, we even tried to reconfigure the SSRS application and also tried to recreate the VM with SQL Server 2019 SSRS enterprise image and retired the steps but we got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure how you configure it. Maybe you can ref this tutorial [Install SSRS ReportServer Databases on Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6620/install-ssrs-reportserver-databases-on-azure-sql-managed-instance/).

HTTP 503 errors can occur during report processing or when you first access a report server:

- If the report server is under high memory pressure, the report server
  will refuse new requests until the current application domain is
  unloaded and a new one instantiated. While requests are refused, you
  will receive HTTP 503 errors. If this situation persists, you should
  do one of the following: add more memory, move the report server
  installation to a computer that has more memory, or change the memory
  configuration settings. For more information about changing the
  configuration settings, see Configuring Available Memory for Report
  Server Applications.
- For HTTP 503 errors that occur when you first open Report Manager or
  access a report server, you must review the HTTP.SYS log file for
  information about what is causing the error. By default, HTTP.SYS
  logging is not enabled. Use the following instructions to enable
  logging on your computer.

Ref this document may be helpful: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159778(v=sql.105).aspx

Related question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/871f6c81-fd8a-4aef-b81f-4b1103cbf28d/http-503-service-unavailable-while-accessing-ssrs-reporting-server-in-azure-vm

HTH.